# dice coefficient above 1

Tags: tensorflow, keras, unet-neural-network

I am using UNET to segment person from image.
I am using COCO dataset to do the same. 
Following are the definitions of loss that i am using to train the model using tensorflow.

```
smooth = 1.

def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)


def dice_coef_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return -dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)

def iou(y_true, y_pred, smooth=1.):
    intersection = K.sum(K.abs(y_true * y_pred), axis=-1)
    union = K.sum(y_true,-1) + K.sum(y_pred,-1) - intersection
    iou = (intersection + smooth) / ( union + smooth)
    return iou
```

I found the implementation of dice and dice loss [here](https://github.com/jocicmarko/ultrasound-nerve-segmentation/blob/master/train.py) .

```
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=lr), loss=dice_coef_loss,
                                metrics=[dice_coef, iou])
```

With batch size of 8 and learning rate 1e-4 i am getting following results in first epoch

Following is the log result:
**Please explain me why dice coefficient is greater than 1.**

Epoch 1/100

2687/8014 [=========>....................] - ETA: 3:04:59 - loss: -1.0958 - dice_coef: 1.0957 - iou: 0.5446

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you normalized `the images` and the `the masks`

Normalized images and mask means that their pixels values are between `0` and `1`

I had the same problem and the cause of it is that I didn't normalize the mask